# Commit fragment after change orientation

Tags: android, fragment, orientation, illegalstateexception

I have FragmentActivity, which contains the layout and layout-land. After changing orientation of the device and then commit() fragment I get an error that I can not fix:

```
IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

I can not lock change screen orientation , as I need to change the layout to layout-land.
How do I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `onCreate` method of your **Fragment** (*not* your FragmentActivity) call `Fragment.setOnRetainInstance(true)`.

You call `commit()` only *once* inside the overrided onCreate method of your FragmentActivity. No need to call it again after changing the orientation. If what you want is saving the Fragment's state after rotation, then `Fragment.setOnRetainInstance(true)` is the guy you are looking for.